# MobileFirst 8.0 Direct Update is not updating the UI after successful update in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have implemented Direct Update in Ionic3 application. Direct Update notification has received, downloaded successfully but UI changes are not getting reflected in application.Please help.

Code Snippet:

```
declare var WL;
declare var wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler;


constructor(public platform: Platform){

 renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mfpjsloaded', () => {
  console.log('--> MyApp mfpjsloaded');
    this.directUpdateHandler();
     this.checkWebUpdate();

    })

}
 checkWebUpdate(){
    console.log('--> checkWebUpdate called');
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
      .then(
        (accessToken) => {
          console.log('--> AuthHandler: obtainAccessToken onSuccess'+JSON.stringify(accessToken));
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('--> AuthHandler: obtainAccessToken onFailure: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      );
  }

directUpdateHandler(){
    console.log('--> MyApp directUpdateHandler called');
     wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = 
      function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
      WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Avalible',' Press update button to 
      download new version', [{
        text :'update',
        handler : function() {
          directUpdateContext.start();
        }
      }]);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Which version of cordova-plugin-mfp you are using ? and also in which platform you are facing this issue ?

Comment: cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2018102517 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation". In Android only so far i have tested.

Comment: Try without calling `directUpdateHandler` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have missed implementing `directUpdateCustomListener`, You are facing this issue.

Two ways to solve this issue :

- Try `Direct Update` feature without using `directUpdateHandler` function, it will work.
- If you are planning to customise the UI for direct update, You have write full definition of the DU which includes implementation of `directUpdateCustomListener` as well. This is mentioned in the following [documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/#customizing-the-direct-update-ui).